# How to disable native keyboard shortcuts in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use vscode for web development. I migrated from intellij idea, installed the keybind extension. unfortunately some keybinds are overriden by the native keyboard layout, which was blocked in intellij by deafult (language specific key combinations łćżź etc).

I tried switching to the US International layout, unfortunately it has some keybinds that result in ¶´¿ö«»

Comment: what keyboard are you using? what OS are you on? what language and keyboard settings have you used at your OS-level? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running `Developer: Inspect Key Mappings` in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to resolve the conflict:
Reset Key bindings:
- Click on File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (or press Ctrl+K Ctrl+S).
- In the Keyboard Shortcuts editor, you'll see a list of available commands and
their associated key bindings.
- To reset a specific key binding, right-click on it and choose "Reset
Key binding".
- Repeat this process for any other custom key bindings you want to reset.

Restart and Remove Extensions:
- Restart VS Code and your computer.
- Remove any potentially buggy extensions that might interfere with key
bindings.